# How to increase all woocommerce product price by percentage

Tags: sql

Im sorry with this noob question.
I would like to ask on how to increase and decrease prices of all woocommerce product via sql command.

Example:
1 have 1000 products with assigned prices i want for increase all product price by 20 percent.

Answer (score -1):

Increase by 20%

```
   UPDATE product
    SET price = price * 1.2
```

decrease by 20%

```
UPDATE product
SET price = price - (price * 0.2)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, im sorry but im a beginner. should i just directly run this in my database?

Comment: what would be the exact code to exexute if running on woocommerce

Comment: No!! its just some psudo code, but should show you the method, I'm not familiar with the woocommerce schema I'm afraid